# Reflection value is not output correctly

Tags: java, reflection

I'm currently working on a project and I decided to create a new Test project to understand where I fail. I recreate the classes that I'm using but in a simple way. My test project looks like this:

[image]

These are the Java classes.

`ChunkGenerator`

```
package chunk;

public interface ChunkGenerator {
    WorldChunkManager getManager();
}
```

`ChunkGeneratorAbstact`

```
package chunk;    

public class ChunkGeneratorAbstract implements ChunkGenerator {
    private WorldChunkManager c;

    public ChunkGeneratorAbstract(WorldChunkManager c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public WorldChunkManager getManager() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

`WorldChunkManager`

```
package chunk;

import java.util.UUID;

public class WorldChunkManager {
    private UUID uuid;

    public WorldChunkManager(UUID uuid){
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

`World`

```
package world;

public class World {
    private WorldProvider provider;

    public World(WorldProvider provider){
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public WorldProvider getProvider(){
        return provider;
    }
}
```

`Main`

```
import chunk.ChunkGenerator;
import chunk.ChunkGeneratorAbstract;
import chunk.WorldChunkManager;
import world.World;
import world.WorldProvider;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        WorldChunkManager manager = new WorldChunkManager(UUID.randomUUID());
        System.out.println("DEFAULT MANAGER UUID:" + manager.getUuid());

        ChunkGeneratorAbstract chunkGeneratorAbstract = new ChunkGeneratorAbstract(manager);
        System.out.println("ChunkGeneratorAbstract: " + chunkGeneratorAbstract.getManager());

        ChunkGenerator generator = new ChunkGenerator() {
            @Override
            public WorldChunkManager getManager() {
                return manager;
            }
        };

        WorldProvider provider = new WorldProvider(generator);
        System.out.println("DEFAULT PROVIDER: " + provider);

        World world = new World(provider);

        Field field = chunkGeneratorAbstract.getClass().getDeclaredField("c");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        WorldChunkManager manager1 = new WorldChunkManager(UUID.randomUUID());
        field.set(chunkGeneratorAbstract, manager1);
        System.out.println("CUSTOM MANAGER UUID: " + manager1.getUuid());

        System.out.println("FINAL:" + world.getProvider().getGenerator().getManager().getUuid());

    }
}
```

And here's the putput:

```
DEFAULT MANAGER UUID:7c85e3ec-2288-4427-aae3-ce9e0b72c581
ChunkGeneratorAbstract: chunk.WorldChunkManager@2b193f2d
DEFAULT PROVIDER: world.WorldProvider@355da254
CUSTOM MANAGER UUID: 98a89e86-3b81-4fc3-8b5d-f22645b1685a
FINAL:7c85e3ec-2288-4427-aae3-ce9e0b72c581
```

As you can see after using reflection and setting the `WorldChunkManager` to a custom one, I try to print out the UUID of the `WorldChunkManager`, but for some reason I keep getting the original one instead of the custom one

Comment: All the code I gave is necessary to understamd the problem

Comment: Also all the classes are not more than 10 lines of code

Comment: OK, since we have a special "I will edit your question and include your offsite code for you" week, I've edited your question.

Comment: I'm really unable to use this fprmatting

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 instances of `ChunkGenerator` in this code:

```
// 1
ChunkGeneratorAbstract chunkGeneratorAbstract = new ChunkGeneratorAbstract(manager);
// 2
ChunkGenerator generator = new ChunkGenerator() {
    @Override
    public WorldChunkManager getManager() {
        return manager; // hard-coded to return manager
    }
};
```

You use reflection to change the `WorldChunkManager` of `chunkGeneratorAbstract`, but the `WorldProvider` was created with a reference to the other one:

```
WorldProvider provider = new WorldProvider(generator);
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^
World world = new World(provider);
```

When you do `world.getProvider().getGenerator()`, it's returning that other `ChunkGenerator`, which is hard-coded to return `manager`.

I suppose you need to create the `WorldProvider` this way to see the behavior you expected:

```
WorldProvider provider = new WorldProvider(chunkGeneratorAbstract);
```

---

Also:

1. The problem is actually unrelated to the use of reflection. If you had made a setter in the `ChunkGeneratorAbstract` class and used it, you would have seen the same problem.
2. Using reflection to set private fields like this is not a good practice. We make the fields of a class (and other members) private as part of a contract with code which uses the class. The contract is that code which uses the class must use it in a certain way (that's dictated by its designer), and must not rely on private members. By using reflection to access private members, you're breaking that contract.

Comment: about second point, guessing by this code it is for a plugin to game engine - so he needs to do this in order to implement some feature not supported by engine that you can't really edit as then you would break compatibility with other plugins that needs to do this. But he just pasted kind of class-stubs to show this issue.

Comment: @GotoFinal That doesn't really change what I said. In that case, whoever authored the API wrote it in a way expecting these fields not to be changed publicly. I felt compelled to post a warning about this use of reflection because for all I know the OP could have started programming 3 days ago and nobody told them that it's abnormal. That doesn't mean they can't still do it. (If they were writing a deserializer, it could even be legitimate, but I doubt they're doing that.)

Comment: As you can guess by that wonderful name "c" this is not an API but obfuscated code. Sure, might be good to leave warning like that, but just saying that in this case it is either reflection or no features :)

Comment: @GotoFinal you got exacly why I'm doing this. The api that I'm using (Spigot) depens on nms code made by Mojang, but, as they don't want you to change stuff, reflectiom is the only way